# Where is the Bamboo restaurant located in Kyoto?

Tags: maps, kyoto

The [Trip Advisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g298564-d1171728-Reviews-Bamboo-Kyoto_Kyoto_Prefecture_Kinki.html) review of Bamboo Restaurant mentions "Higashiyamasanjo Higashiiru Minamigawa, Higashiyama-ku, Kyoto" but Google Maps is totally failing to find that location.

Where can you find it on a map of Kyoto? Alternatively, how would you get there from Kyoto Station?

Comment: I'll let the experts provide a proper answer, but tablelog apparently says it's close to a train station http://tabelog.com/kyoto/A2603/A260301/26000573/dtlmap/ and here's a link to the Japanese Trip Advisor version, which has an address in Japanese: http://www.tripadvisor.jp/Restaurant_Review-g298564-d1171728-Reviews-Bamboo-Kyoto_Kyoto_Prefecture_Kinki.html#REVIEWS . I'm pretty illiterate in Japanese, so I searched using the phone number.

Comment: Searching by the phone number is such a useful tip! I found several other places this afternoon using that method.

Answer (score 4):

It's [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%E6%99%A9boo+%E6%9D%B1%E5%B1%B1%E4%B8%89%E6%9D%A1/@35.00947,135.778793,3a,75y,177.02h,90t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1s_7PuNzOl3ESDH8tIE1XTJA!2e0!4m2!3m1!1s0x600108e85802bd89:0x95cc3895e8dad90d)! Right next the train station exit. You can find it on google maps by focusing into the area of the [train station](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Higashiyama+Station/@35.009431,135.779717,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x600108e86412eb77:0xafcaa68916b01d27) (search for Higashiyama Station, Kyoto) and then entering the [name of the restaurant into the search field](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%E6%99%A9boo+%E6%9D%B1%E5%B1%B1%E4%B8%89%E6%9D%A1/@35.009306,135.778748,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x600108e85802bd89:0x95cc3895e8dad90d).

On top of that, there is the (Japanese) website tabelog, where you can enter the name of the restaraurant into the [right search field](http://tabelog.com/rstLst/?vs=1&lid=hd_search1&SrtT=trend&sw=%25E6%2599%25A9Boo&sk=%25E6%2599%25A9Boo&sa=) (Keyword) and the first result is the one. They also [have a map](http://tabelog.com/kyoto/A2603/A260301/26000573/dtlmap/).

Alternatively, there is gurunavi which has also english pages. You need to transliterate the name into "bambuh" and then [will find it too](http://rds.gnavi.co.jp/lang/en/?word=BAMBUH%20HIGASHIYAMASANJOU).